# How to get and fetch url employee id in jsp dynamically

Tags: oracle, jsp

I have one dynamic jsp page where i enter details in database in this page iam getting url string from other tables like below format **EmployeeRegistration/Employee_vendor_approve.jsp?employee_id=25666**
Now my question is i want to fetch this employee_id in dynamic textbox user cannot edit this field i tried for using **session.getAttribute("employee_id");** but no work anyone can please help me here is my javascript and jsp code

Javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
function getinput() 
{ 
index ++; 
var singleRecord = ""; 
**singleRecord += " Employee_id : <input type='text' name='txt_Employee_id"+index+"'>";** //here employee_id should fetch dynamically from other jsp page
singleRecord += " Project_name : <input type='text' name='txt_project_name"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "Project/Task : <input type='text' name='txt_Header"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "Description : <input type='text' name='txt_description"+index+"'>"; 
<!--singleRecord+="Date : <input type='date'  name='datainsertdate"+index+"'>"; --->
singleRecord += "<hr/>"; 
$("#inputs").append(singleRecord); 
$("#count").val(index); 
}

</script> 

</head> 

<body background="123-slideshow\blue_background.jpg">
<form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post"> 

     <br><br><br><br>    
<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count"/> 



<div id="inputs"> 
</div> 
<button type="button" onclick="getinput()" class="button button5">Add</button> 

&nbsp; 
<button type="submit" class="button button2">Submit</button> 


</form> 
</body> 

</html>
```

JSP

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("count")); 

if(count >0){ 

for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){ 


 //employee_id_numeric=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("employee_id")+i);
 String employee_id = request.getParameter("txt_Employee_id"+i);
String txt_project_name = request.getParameter("txt_project_name"+i); 
String get_header = request.getParameter("txt_Header"+i); 
String get_department = request.getParameter("txt_Department"+i); 
String get_description = request.getParameter("txt_description"+i); 

ps.setString(1, employee_id);   
ps.setString(2, txt_project_name); 
ps.setString(3, get_header); 
ps.setString(4, get_department); 
ps.setString(5, get_description); 

ps.addBatch(); 
} 
} 
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: can you make your question more clearly? I do not understand what you want to do

Comment: my question is how can i value(employee_id) fetch one page to another?

Comment: For entering i need 20 reputation which is i dont have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<%=request.getParameter("employee_id") %>` in your jsp code,such as below:

```
<script>
function getinput() 
{ 
index ++; 
var singleRecord = ""; 
singleRecord += " Employee_id : <input type='text' name='txt_Employee_id"+index+"' value='<%=request.getParameter("employee_id") %>'>";
singleRecord += " Project_name : <input type='text' name='txt_project_name"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "Project/Task : <input type='text' name='txt_Header"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "Description : <input type='text' name='txt_description"+index+"'>"; 
singleRecord += "<hr/>"; 
$("#inputs").append(singleRecord); 
$("#count").val(index); 
}
</script>
```